Optimizing Wind Park Layout Using Direct Action-to-Input Mapping
I’m optimizing a black-box objective function where the task is to find the optimal turbine locations in a wind park. Previously, I used a PPO reinforcement learning approach with a step-by-step method: the agent started at a random position in each episode and moved incrementally toward the optima. This worked well for a simpler case, where I was adding a new turbine to an existing layout, and the model converged on two near-optimal solutions.
Now, I want to scale this to optimize the entire turbine layout. Instead of moving in small steps toward the goal, I’m considering an approach where the actions directly represent the new input locations (e.g., the specific turbine coordinates), bypassing the incremental steps.
My questions are: Is this even possible? Should I stick with PPO, or is there a more suitable method for this type of direct-action-to-input mapping? What adjustments would I need to make to the reward structure or overall RL framework to accommodate this?
For testing, I’m currently using a substitute objective function with 10 inputs since the original one is computationally expensive:
def dummy_objective_function(self, inputs):
    inputs = np.array(inputs).flatten()
    base = -np.sum((inputs - np.arange(1, 11))**2)
    bumps = 5 * np.sin(inputs).sum() + 3 * np.cos(inputs * 2).sum()
    return base + bumps

I’d appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to best implement this approach.
